# R/GIS: Overlay GADM data with data from other sources?

Tags: r, gis

I have administrative boundary data from the [Global Administrative Areas Database](http://www.gadm.org). Plotting subdivisions with this data is very easy. For example, if I want to overplot geocoded data contained in the file `mydata` on counties in Florida, I download the "level 2" for the US, and then use this code:

```
load("/home/anindya/Desktop/DELETE/USA_adm2.RData")
temp = as.data.frame(gadm) *Code for eyeballing structure of data
florida = gadm[344:410,]
plot(florida); points(mydata$longitude, mydata$latitude)
```

But how do you overlay other information on this, say for topography and waterways? I am particularly interested in data from [Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/) and the [Global Lakes and Wetlands Database](https://secure.worldwildlife.org/science/data/item1877.html).

FOLLOW-UP EDIT: Many thanks to Paul for a soloution to the problem. I had crossposted a variation of this question on [here at gis.stackexchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20099/how-to-overlay-map-layers-shp-and-csv-in-r), where R.K. gave an excellent answer. Do read up on it as well.

Comment: Take a look at http://gis.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sorry I couldn't find something directly relevant. Sure there should be a simple function for overlaying two plots with different kinds of details on the same geographical area?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you are asking about how to superimpose different geographic layers as one would using a GUI GIS.

This is straightforward if the data is in a `Spatial*` object (e.g. `SpatialPoints, SpatialLines, SpatialPolygons` etc. from the `sp` package) or as a `Raster*` object from the `raster` package.  The `plot()` methods in both of these packages can handle this superimposition if the parameter `add=TRUE` is given.

To get your vector-based geographic data into `Spatial*` objects you can use functions from the `maptools` package (e.g. `readShapePoly()` reads ESRI polygon shapefiles).  Rasters from a variety of file specifications can be loaded using `raster()` and additional formats are available if the `rgdal` package is installed.

Here is an example of superimposing geographic data types using fabricated geographic data.  First create some example data on a UTM grid:

```
library(sp)
library(raster)

## Create a RasterLayer object and fill with random values
baseRaster <- raster(nrow=100, ncol=100, 
    xmn=0, xmx=100, ymn=0, ymx=100,
    crs= "+proj=utm")
baseRaster[] <- runif(ncell(baseRaster))

## Create a second raster to superimpose
## It should contain NA values where it is transparent
supRaster <- baseRaster
supRaster[] <- NA
supRaster[cellFromCol(supRaster, 48:52)] <- 1


## Create SpatialPoints object to superimpose on these
loc <- SpatialPoints(cbind(seq(10, 90, by=10), seq(10, 90, by=10)))
```

Now do the plots:

```
## Plot base raster
plot(baseRaster)

## Superimpose second raster in a different colour
## Turn off legend
plot(supRaster, add=TRUE, col="blue", legend=FALSE)

## Superimpose points and make them big and colourful
plot(loc, add=TRUE, pch=20, cex=3, col="red")
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Note that overlays like this only work if the datasets have the same coordinate reference system. R won't do coordinate transformation on-the-fly so you have to use spTransform from rgdal if, say, you've got one set of data in lat-long coords and one in some UTM metric grid.

Comment: @Spacedman - transformations to a common CRS is often essential, but doing it in R remains a bit of mystery to me.  I have asked this follow-up question at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9230318/