# Combining geographic layers with different projections in R

Tags: r, gis

EDIT:  I have reworded the title question slightly, and adjusted the text to respond to the comment by @DWin.

Combining geographic layers that are projected and not projected can be challenging.  Often, it seems, some transformation is necessary, as geographic layers come from different products and publishers.

I am aware that R has several tools to perform geographic transformations.  For example:

1. For objects of class `Spatial*` in the `sp` package, the `spTransform()` function in the `rgdal` package can be used; and,
2. For objects of class `Raster*` in the `raster` package, the `projectRaster()` function can be used.

Here is a specific task that I would like to accomplish in R:  Transform to UTM grid Zone 15N (Datum: NAD83) a polygons layer describing lakes in a UTM grid Zone 15N (Datum: NAD27) projection (this is in an ESRI shapefile format).

Comment: This question seems overly broad, and you are asking the reader to either offer general opinions or asking them to construct their own examples. I see no reason why you should not narrow the question AND be expected to provide dummy examples creating structures that can be used to illustrate specific solutions.

Comment: @Dwin have reworded the title of the question and the text.  The requested task is much narrower.

Comment: It turned out to have a more general answer than I expected and thanks to you and @Spaceman.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The useful thing here is the epsg database included in rgdal.

```
epsgs = make_EPSG()
subset(epsgs,grepl("15N",epsgs$note))

[etc]
      code
2703 26715                         # NAD27 / UTM zone 15N  [etc]
2851 26915                         # NAD83 / UTM zone 15N  [etc]
[etc]
```

Those codes are what you need in spTransform. If your lakes are in a shapefile with that NAD27 projection, then:

```
require(maptools)
lakes = readShapeSpatial("lakes.shp")
proj4string(lakes)=CRS("+init=epsg:26715")
```

should give you the lakes as supplied (note I dont think readShapeSpatial will read a .prj file with a shapefile set, so I've set it here explicitly)

Now to convert to NAD83 datum version of UTM zone 15N:

```
lakes83 = spTransform(lakes,CRS("+init=epsg:26915"))
```

Rasters are a bit trickier since they generally involve a warp so that you end up with a regular grid in your projected coordinate system - you can't just transform the coordinates of the corners...

Comment: epsg db is v useful, see also www.spatialreference.org and http://www.epsg-registry.org/